# cannot transition from error action

Tags: ember.js

I want to transition to a "oops" route when there is error loading model. My router looks like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

export default
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('invitations', {path: '/invitations'});
  this.resource('oops');
});
```

InivitationsRoute has error action defined as:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default
Ember.Route.extend({

  actions: {

    error: function(error, transition) {

      if (error && error.status === 500) {
        transition.abort();
        this.transitionTo('oops',{'a':'b'});
      }

      // Return true to bubble this event to any parent route.
      return false;
    }

  }
});
```

Now the problem i am seeing is, if I pass an object to the **this.transitionTo('oops',{'a':'b'});** , then ember doesn't even try to do a transition, but if I just did **this.transitionTo('oops');**, it would transition to the route. The problem is I want to pass error JSON as model to this route!

My OopsRoute is minimalistic :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default
Ember.Route.extend({

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
  }
});
```

Can't seem to understand why it wouldn't work! 
Using ember : 1.11.3

Comment: What version of Ember Data? The reason I am asking is the error object was changed in Ember Data 1.13.

Comment: We are not using ember data at the moment, just using plain javascript objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember thinks that your `{ "a":"b" }` is a dynamic segment because you haven't specified the path for the oops resource.

If you change your resource to `this.resource("oops", { path: '/' }` then the transition will work, however your data still won't be treated as a model, (I think) will treat the `{ "a":"b" }` object as queryParams to try to find a model.

Since your oops route doesn't really have a model and will just be used to display error messaging (I'm assuming), I would do something like use a service to persist the error message between routes. Something like:

```
// services/error-messages.js
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  errorMessage: null
});


// routes/invitations.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  errorMessages: Ember.inject.service(),

  actions: {
    error: function () {
      var errors = this.get("errorMessages") // the error-messages service
      errors.set("errorMessage", "Something has gone wrong!");
    }
  }
});


// routes/oops.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  errorMessages: Ember.inject.service()

  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    var errors = this.get("errorMessages");
    controller.set("errorToDisplayInTemplate", errors.get("errorMessage");
  }
});


// templates/oops.hbs
{{errorToDisplayInTemplate}}
```

And then obviously you'd want to `null` out the error message in the service whenever you leave the oops page.

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a try tomorrow and let you know how it goes - but the documentation for transitionTo never mentions the second argument to transitionTo is query params, but rather should be model!

Comment: Yeah I was confused by the docs as well, someone can correct me on this but I think that would only work if your route has a dynamic segment that matches a model attribute. For example if your route path was `/oops/:id` and you passed it a model with an ID attribute, it would probably use it as the model. I haven't tested that theory though but you could give it a quick try.

Comment: update to my above comment - looks like this is the case, here's a JSbin example of showing your `a:"b"` model http://emberjs.jsbin.com/luvuharawo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now - although my oops resource doesn't need a dynamic segment but I guess there is no escaping, or use your alternative approach of using service. Thanks again.